# My ArrayList Not Returning all the elements

Tags: java, arraylist

My Java Program below displays all elements in the ArrayList when I use the System.out.println static method. However it only displays Just one element in the ArrayList when I return the list in a method. I will appreciate some direction on what am doing wrong:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileProcessor {  
  static List<String> theList = null;

  /**
   * 
   * @return List
   */
  public static List<String> processFiles() {      
    try {    
      File f = new File("/Data/fileDump");
      String[] listOfFiles = f.list();

      for(String eachFile: listOfFiles) {  
        if(eachFile.startsWith("hawk") == true) { 
          theList = new ArrayList<>(); 
          theList.add(eachFile); 
          return theList;
        }
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return theList;
  }


  public static void main(String[]args) {
    List<String> dataList = FileProcessor.processFiles(); 
    for(String strg: dataList) {
      if(strg != null) {
        System.out.println(strg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read over ["how to ask a good question"](/help-how-to-ask) and then come back to your post so you can edit it a little: the code's all over the place, it's good form to make sure to not just have enough detail, but also present well formatted code.

Comment: You create a list *inside the loop*, add *one element to it*, and then *return it*. Can you see why it's a one-element list?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function with the following.

```
      public static List<String>  processFiles() { 
          List<String> theList = null;
          try {    

             File  f = new File("/Data/fileDump");
             String[] listOfFiles = f.list();
             theList = new ArrayList<>(); // initialisation moved outside of loop
             for(String eachFile:   listOfFiles) {  
                 if(eachFile.startsWith("hawk") == true){              
                    theList.add(eachFile); 
               }
             }
             return theList;// return statement moved outside of the loop

          } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return theList;
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to return outside your for block. Otherwise you're returning with one element. You're also re-instantiating the list at every loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. Only a couple changes. I put remarks where I moved or deleted code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileProcessor {  
static  List<String> theList = null;





 /**
  * 
  * @return List
  */
 public static List<String>  processFiles() {      

      try {    


          File  f = new File("/Data/fileDump");

          String[] listOfFiles = f.list();
          theList = new ArrayList<>();  /* Move this here */
          for(String eachFile:   listOfFiles) {  
             if(eachFile.startsWith("hawk") == true){
                theList.add(eachFile);

               /* Deleted the extra return. The one at the end will handle it. */

             }
          }

      } catch(Exception e) {


         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    return theList;
   }


    public static void main(String[]args){
     List<String> dataList = FileProcessor.processFiles(); 
     for(String strg: dataList){
         if(strg != null){
            System.out.println(strg);
         }
     }


    }
```

}